# Have expanding div detect window size to prevent going beyond window barrier

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div that's made draggable with jQueryUI and when certain features are pressed it expands downward (The expansion is animated with different CSS values and transition properties) to show the extra options. However when the div is placed low on the page and is then expanded it goes beyond the page limits. I would like the div to still expand however get pushed up when the bottom is touching the bottom of the page.

```
                    $('#normalLegend').draggable({
                        scroll: false,
                        containment: 'window'
                    });
```

That's my draggable div. It cannot go beyond the window size when dragged there however if expanded near the edges of the window it will go beyond the window barrier. If clicked to be dragged again it will auto correct itself and center itself back into the window but I'd rather have it get pushed up than jump to the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

Its not good way to do thing, if user want to keep the div down you wont let it do that, your code will always push the div up, which will cause in as a bug to the code,

```
         $("#normalLegend").draggable({
            appendTo: 'body',
            scroll: false,
            containment: "body"
        });
```

add appendto body so that your scroll is off  and div remains on screen

I will recommend to think again for your approach as a user point of view